# Replay/rework TCP packets (Man in the middle)

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, wireshark

I have a few Virtual Machines on my computer, that communicate with each other through a host private network.

I want to simulate a man in the middle attack between those machines. All the tools I have found to run a MITM yet are only monitoring packets, but I didn't find any tool that could actually replay them or alter them.

I found a tool called ostinato that could manipulate packets. I used it to replay some packets that I received with Wireshark, but the target didn't answer (I think it is linked with the Timestamp and some other fields in the TCP window).

Do you know any tool that could allow me to catch/sniff a TCP packet on the network, and rework/replay it in a way that I can get an answer from the server?

Thank you!

Comment: If you alter a TCP segment (not packet) you need to recalculate the checksum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Hex Injector can help, which is a sniffer and a packet injector:

https://n0where.net/versatile-packet-injector-and-sniffer-hexinject/